# Send eloquent query to a job

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a fairly complex query with a lot of data that gets fetched. Currently I have two jobs with similar complex queries and now I need to write a third job. The queries are also used for datatables, thus I have to make sure they are the same which is not optimal, I have redundant code. However, I would like to improve my code and simply use one job that will accept any query.

What I would like to do is pass the query used for my datatables to a single job that takes any query and runs it creating an excel export. However I am not sure it is possible to serialize the actual query instead of the result since the query may take a long time to execute and I would like to run it via the Redis queue I have.

If I try to pass the Eloquent query to a job I get "You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances"

**How can I get rid of this problem and send the query to the job to be executed?**

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Jobs by default use the **SerializesModels** trait so check if your Job is using that trait. Also you cannot serialize PDO objects which is why you get the exception.

To get rid of the error you can take out the trait but IMHO I wouldn't pass your Eloquent query to a Job. Instead keep the queries in the Job execution based on a **minimum of required parameters** passed to the Job.

> “What I would like to do is pass the query used for my datatables to a single job that takes any query and runs it creating an excel export”

A query or series of queries can most likely be described as a task in words, so create a separate Job for each specific purpose. If you make a single Job for all your tasks it would be less readable, harder to maintain & conclude a distinction between the purpose of the Job.

Instead I'd remove the "redundant" code you speak of, create a Job in which you write the common code & extend this Job into separate Jobs. In terms of re-usable code, you could use a Repository or a Service & call it from your separate Jobs.